# How can I share a small part of my repository with somebody?

Tags: git, bitbucket

My colleague is going to work on some projects for me whilst I am away on holiday, so naturally I have shared my repository with him to give him access to my code base.

However, there are dozens of folders in there and not every folder in the repository is relevant to him.

I have only recently started using git and haven't found anything online that implies that this is possible.

How can I share only the relevant folders in my repository?

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do that.  In git, commits represent complete snapshots of repo content.  To create a version of the repo containing only certain folders, you'd have to create a new set of commits with only those folders - i.e. a separate history.  Then it will be difficult to integrate work done on that repo back into your original repo.

This is one of the reasons why each project should have its own repo.  The term "each project" here is a bit vague, but the point is a repo should contain the group of assets that will typically be worked on / change together.  People who are used to TFVC and the like argue for so-called "monorepo" structures; if you use such a structure, you are working against the grain of git.

If you have a group of related projects, you can put them each in their own repo and either (1) use build tooling to document the dependencies and assemble them as needed (which is my recommendation), or (2) use submodules.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.

Suppose your repository has 4 subfolders(`foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4`) and you want to share 2 of them(`foo2 and foo4`) to your colleague, and your branch is `master`.

The tree of your repository:

```
.
├── foo1
├── foo2
├── foo3
└── foo4
```

If you are not familiar with git, you could make a new clone before doing the following steps. Even if it does not succeed, your original repo won't be messed up.

1) Make a branch without `foo1` and `foo3`:

```
git checkout -b base master
git rm -rf foo1 foo3
git commit -m 'base for colleague'
```

2) Create a bundle with an initial branch `colleague` from `base` for your colleague:

```
git checkout --orphan colleague base
git commit -m 'init colleague'
git bundle create colleague.bundle colleague
```

3) Share the file `colleague.bundle` to your colleague. It can be used as a read-only remote repository.

4) Your colleague clones from the bundle and creates his/her own repo `myrepo`:

```
git clone <path to colleague.bundle> -- myrepo
cd myrepo
git checkout -b master origin/colleague
#in the repo, there are only foo2 and foo4
#make his/her changes to foo2 and foo4, and commit them
```

5) Your colleague gives you his/her new commits and you apply them. Here is one of the possible methods:

```
#your colleague creates a bundle 'return.bundle' and send it to you
git bundle create return.bundle master

#you fetch his/her 'master' from the bundle and apply the new commits to your own 'master'
git fetch <path to return.bundle> master:from_my_colleague
git checkout master
git cherry-pick colleague..from_my_colleague

#after all is done, you could delete those branches
git branch -D base colleague from_my_colleague
```

The committer of these new commits will be you and the authors of them are your colleague. At first, you can also simply push your branch `colleague` to a real remote repository and ask your colleague to fetch it and create `master` from it. But it may involve repository management like repository creation and access control while a bundle is more straightforward. And at last, your colleague can also simply push his/her `master` to a real remote repository, and then you fetch it to your repository and apply the new commits to your `master`.